# IIS Regex to allow space

Tags: regex, iis

I have a regex in my IIS to accept some parameter and then redirect the url.

```js
^TestData/([\S]+)
```

So if a url -> ../testdata/1234/CA   is there then it successfully proceeds. But if the data has any space such as ->  ../testdata/MO%20-%20L12/CA. Then it fails.

%20 -> Space.

So, how can I accept even spaces. My final received data will be-

D1: ../testdata/1234/CA
D2: 1234/CA

Comment: Repace `[\S]+` with `.+`

Comment: Thanks. Got it. It worked